# pdftotext get font information (font-family, style, size)

Tags: text-extraction, pdftotext, poppler, pdf-scraping, xpdf

I'm using "`pdftotext -bbox file.pdf`" to convert a `pdf` file into `HTML`.

Here's a sample line from the output:

```
<word xMin="351.852025" yMin="42.548936" xMax="365.689478"
yMax="47.681498">foo</word>
```

Is there a way to get font information for every word like:

- font family, e.g. Verdana
- style, i.e. none, bold, italic
- size, e.g. font size 9

I'm interested in knowing if either the poppler or xpdf version of pdftotext can do this.